# ExpressJS - Error Handler Not Handling Any Errors

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with my error handler like below:

```
export const errorHandler = (
    error: Error,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: (error: Error) => void,
  ) => {
    console.log("TEST");
    next(error);
}
```

It is very simple but I have a problem with launching it on errors, here is my index.js:

```
export const server = http.createServer(app);

const initServer = () => {
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit }));
  app.use(morgan("[:date[iso]] :method :url :status :response-time ms"));

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(router);

  app.use(errorHandler); //IS HERE

  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    logger.info(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
};

initServer();
```

Can someone tell me why it is not working when I call an request when I set:

```
throw new Error("ERROR");
```

Thanks for any answer, thanks!

PS. `router` file is here:

```
export const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get("/account/login", login);

//and more...
```

Comment: Where are you putting the `throw new Error()`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose your response within the errorHandler middleware... let me show you how I do this

I create a generic middleware which is used in every route

> this is in Typescript, if you use only Javascript just remove the types (it's easy to port)

```
return async function (req: Request, resp: Response, next) {
        try {
            const response = await fn(req, resp, next);
            resp.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (e) {
           // here you can handle the error the way you wish to

           // I throw all my errors as ErrorObject ( a custom class)
           // so I can send user formatted errors, you can implement this
           // however you wish to
           
            if (e instanceof ErrorObject) {
                const error = e.json();
                resp.status(e.statusCode).send(error);
            } else next(e);
        }
    };
```

Now any of your route should use this middleware as follows

```
router.post(
  "/your-route",
  expressResponse((req, resp) => {
     // do want you want
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express 4.x or earlier, and you are using asynchronous route handlers, [you need to catch any encountered errors](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) and pass them explicitly to `next()` in order for them to be processed by your error handler.

I have a helper function I use to wrap async handlers in my projects that looks like this:

```js
/**
 * Wrapper for async route handlers that passes Promise-based errors to next().
 *
 * NOTE: Starting with Express 5 (which is not released as of this note) exceptions
 *  in async middleware will be handled as expected, and this asyncMiddleware will
 *  no longer be needed.
 *
 * When an async route handler rejects a Promise, it is important that the
 * Express error handler be invoked to end the request cleanly. This wrapper
 * function supports the idiomatic:
 *
 *  router.use('/path', asyncMiddleware(async(req, res) => {
 *     await db.save();     // permitted b/c we are async
 *     if (something_bad) {
 *          throw(...);     // reject promise, and invokes Express error handler
 *     }
 *     return res.send({}); // resolve promise normally
 *  }
 */
export const asyncMiddleware =
    fn => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
    };
```